# File lock errors after moving files in code

Tags: c#, system.io.file

I was using the following code to move a file into a folder

```
File.Move(Source,Dest);
```

I then try to open and read the file, in the next method, but I kept getting file locked by process errors.

So I changed the file move to the following code

```
public async static Task<bool> MoveFileAsync(string sourceFileName, string destinationFileName)
{
    using(FileStream sourceStream = File.Open(sourceFileName, FileMode.Open))
    {
        using(FileStream destinationStream = File.Create(destinationFileName))
        {
            try
            {
                await sourceStream.CopyToAsync(destinationStream);
                File.Delete(sourceFileName);
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I keep getting errors that the file locked

Any ideas on how to prevent this from happening.

This is all using a FileSystemWatcher to monitor the folder... the code is below. I can confirm none of these error happen when I drag and drop files into the folders... even when I drag multiple files...
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

```
namespace DocumentManager.RepositoryService
{
    internal class MonitorDropFolder
    {
        public string RepositoryPath { get; set; }
        public FileSystemWatcher Watcher { get; set; }

        public MonitorDropFolder ()
        {
            Watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            Watcher.Path = @"c:\Repository\DropLocation";
            Watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName;
            Watcher.Filter = "*.docx";
            Watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnCreatedHandler);

            StartMonitoring();
        }

        public void StartMonitoring()
        {
            Watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }

        public void StopMonitoring()
        {
            Watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
        }

        private void OnCreatedHandler(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        { 
            if(e.ChangeType == WatcherChangeTypes.Created)
            {
                //don't process temporary files
                if (Path.GetFileName(e.FullPath).Substring(0, 1) == "~" || Path.GetFileName(e.FullPath).Substring(0, 1) == "$")
                    return;


                var result = convert(e.FullPath, GetDocStatus(e.Name)).Result;
                FileService.MoveNativeToDraft(e.FullPath);
            }
        }

        private async Task<bool> convert(string fileName, string docStatus)
        {
            try
            {
                ConvertWordToPDF convertor = new ConvertWordToPDF();
                var task = Task.Run(()=>convertor.Convert(fileName, docStatus));
                await task;


                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Update:
I am calling the code like this...

```
public static void MoveIntoRepository(string sourceFile)
{
    string destinationDir = @"C:\Repository\DropLocation\";
    var result = MoveFileAsync(sourceFile, Path.Combine(destinationDir, Path.GetFileName(sourceFile))).Result;
}
```

I also tried getting around the file lock like this...

```
bool isFileLocked = isLocked(filename);
int numTries = 0;
while(isFileLocked)
{
    numTries++;
    if (numTries > 100)
        throw new Exception("FileLock Error");

    ///the following is actually in a called method
    byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
    ///... rest of code here

    Thread.Sleep(500);
    isFileLocked = isLocked(filename);
}
```

which calls this method

```
private static bool isLocked(string filename)
{
    try 
    {           
        FileStream st = new FileStream();
        st = File.Open(filename,FileMode.Open);
        st.Close();
        return false;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return true;
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're using a fsw to detect file changes there is a high probability you're trying to access the file when the OS or some other program is using it. File.Move will only lock the file during the copy operation, and only the destination one, source file is shared for read.

Comment: Also, you haven't posted the code were you call the MoveFileAsync function and that can be the place where the error lies, add it to the question.

Comment: @ChrisOBrien did you find out the reason why the destination file was locked after calling Move method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my comments below in code:

```
using(FileStream sourceStream = File.Open(sourceFileName, FileMode.Open))
{
    using(FileStream destinationStream = File.Create(destinationFileName))
    {
        try
        {
            await sourceStream.CopyToAsync(destinationStream);
            // The sourceFileName file is locked since you are inside the 
            // the using statement. Move statement for deleting file to
            // outside the using.
            File.Delete(sourceFileName);
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
// Move it here
```